# [SpringCloudGateway]: Post filters are not executed after endpoint redirection timeout

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

We have implemented couple of custom Ordered Global Pre and Post filters in spring cloud gateway application. These pre global filters are getting executed for any incoming requests before redirecting to configured endpoint. And all post global filters are getting executed after endpoint call is completed successfully and response is received.

We have observed that these post filters are getting executed for other 4xx, like 404 (Not Found), 401(Unauthorized), and 5xx, like 503(Service Unavailable), 500 (Internal Server error), error response from endpoint call.

However, we have observed that these post global filters are not getting executed when the endpoint call is getting timeout, that is 504 Gateway Timeout response is received. Global response timeout is configured as 30sec as follows and endpoint call is taking more than 30 sec to process the request:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 30000
        response-timeout: 30000
```

Global Post filters are implemented in following pattern:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        final ResponseCookie  resCookie = ResponseCookie.from(this.cookieName, "invalidated").httpOnly(true).secure(true).path("/").maxAge(0).build();
        exchange.getResponse().addCookie(resCookie);
   }));
}

@Override
public int getOrder() {
   return POST_FILTER_BASE_ORDER - 3;  // POST_FILTER_BASE_ORDER = 1000
}
```

This post filter executes for 404 and 503 response status from endpoint, however fails to execute when API gateway times-out the endpoint call (endpoint take more than 30sec to respond).

Is it an expected behavior from Spring Cloud Gateway framework or defect?

Any help to resolve the issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing details of your filter implementation, it will be very difficult to provide any useful feedback

Comment: @spencergibb The pattern of implemented post filters is updated in the description. All 3 post filters are implemented in above pattern. The post filter to handle 4xx and 5xx response is in development and not formalised due to issue observed in 504 timeout flow where post filters are not getting executed. There is no change implemented in ideal filter chain execution. The post filters are getting executed for 404, 401 and 503 response status.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, likely for the timeout, the global filters won't be executed since webflux will take over exception handling. Look for how to handle exceptions in the webflux docs (on Mobile). There's a global exception handler, but I can't remember the details

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb for sharing the pointer. In that case, could you please confirm the standard behaviour of spring cloud gateway in case of any error/exception encountered in endpoint call? Since we observed difference in filter chain execution. Post filters gets executed for 404 and 503 error however not executed for 504(gateway timeout endpoint call). This will help in implementing robust error mechanism.

Comment: We are migrating existing app built on Netflix Zuul to spring cloud Gateway so we need to keep the filter execution flow in sync. In Netflix Zuul, in case of any error in pre filter or endpoint call, post filters are always executed. We need to execute post filters in case of any error in endpoint call in spring cloud Gateway app as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try return the order value as -1 like so:

```
@Override
public int getOrder() {
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion.. in that case what should be the order for global pre-filters? I couldn't find any recommendations on global filter anywhere.